# why do GitHub Actions over consume minutes?

Tags: macos, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm currently working on CI for a repository with `GitHub Actions`.

I noticed that the used time with every CI is 10x times of the actual cost time to run the job.

Let's say if the job takes `1 minute`, the used time in billing will be `10 minutes` instead. What seems to be the problem here?

I'm currently working with macOS, Xcode, iOS build.

Here is my `ios.yml` file:

```
name: Application Build Flow

on:
push:
  branches: [ "main" ]
pull_request:
  branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Default Scheme
    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Configure Build and Run Build
        run: xcodebuild build -project cicd.xcodeproj -scheme CICD -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=16.0,name=iPhone 13" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

Comment: is this because of macOS? https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions#minute-multipliers

Comment: @banyan I think you are right. That’s some mind-blowing cost. Look like I need to use ubuntu runner instead.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because of the action minutes ratio for the OS, as indicated by @banyan. That is linked to their licensing and hosting costs.

For reference:

- Ubuntu minutes are 1 to 1
- Windows minutes are 1 to 2
- And MacOS minutes are 1 to 10 minutes